# Is the following transformation h from R to S a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Do the following ring homomorphisms with identity exist from $R$ to $S$?

a) $R=\mathbb{Q}[X]$, $S=\mathbb{Q}$, $f(X^2-2)=0$

b) $R=\mathbb{R}[X]$, $S=\mathbb{C}$, $f(X^2+4)=0$

I know the following fact:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $f \in R[X]$ and $r \in R$, then
$$ \text{ev}_r : R[X] \to R,  \text{ ev}_r(f) = f(r)\text{ is a ring homomorphism.}$$

To check b), I use this fact:

We have $2i \in \mathbb{C}$, and $\text{ev}_{2i}(f) = f(2i) = 0$, it holds, also $\text{ev}_{2i}(1_{\mathbb{R}[X]})=1_{\mathbb{C}}.$

How to deal with a)?
I can't use that trick because we have $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. And from the definition, it's not clear how to check whether it is a homomorphism.

Comment: You should not denote the homomorphism and the polynomial by $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint (for a)): suppose $f$ is a ring homomorphism. What is the value of $f(X)$?

Comment: Let $f$ be a ring homomorphism, it must satisfy that $f(X^2) = f(X) \cdot f(X)$. However, under the given condition that $f(X^2 - 2) = 0$, we have $f(X^2) = f(2)$. Since $f$ must preserve the multiplicative identity, $f(2) = 2$.

Therefore, $f(X)^2 = 2$. In $\mathbb{Q}$, there is no rational number whose square is 2, hence, no such $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $f(X)^2 = 2$, so a ring homomorphism under these conditions cannot exist.

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Thank you, just one more question, is the method with function ev good and sufficient?

Comment: @JimmieHilberto yes, it is the standard method